# What will happen if my kafka consumer group is changed after each restart

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Let’s say for instance, my kafka consumer (in Consumer Group 1) is reading messages from Kafka Topic A.

Now if that consumer consumes 12 messages before failing.
When the consumer starts up again, and now it has different consumer group (i.e. consumer group 2),
Question 1 -? On restart, will it continue from where it left off in the offset (or position) because that offset is stored by Kafka and/or ZooKeeper or will it start consuming messages from 1st message.

Question 2-> Is there a way to ensure that on restart (When consumer has different consumer group), it still start consuming from where it left off before restarting?

Just to give you the context, i am trying to update in-memory caches in each node/server on receiving a message on kafka topic. In order to do that, i am using a different consumer group for each node/server so that each message is consumed by all the nodes/servers to update in-memory cache. Please let me know if there are better ways to do this. Thanks!

Comment: If you want an in memory cache, then you can use a KTable

Answer (score 1):

Consumer offsets are maintained per consumer group and hence if you have a different consumer group on each restart you can make use of the `auto.offset.reset` property

The auto.offset.reset property specifies

- What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):

  - earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset

    latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset

    none: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group

    anything else: throw exception to the consumer.

Having informed about the current approach - I believe you should relook at the design and it would be better to have a different consumer group per node but ensure to keep the same consumer group name per node even after a restart. This is a suggestion based on the info provided but there could be better solutions as well after going into the detail of the design/implementation.